# SQL Server 2012 FETCH Ignore dynamically and get all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL Server 2012 query:

```
DECLARE @page int
SET @page = 1

DECLARE @recordslimit int
SET @recordslimit =1

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OVER () as totalrecords
    ,[shiftoverrideid]
    ,[employeeid]
    ,[masterentity]
    ,[date]
    ,[intime]
    ,[outtime]
    ,[workhours]
    ,[lunchout]
    ,[lunchin]
    ,[isactive]
    ,[isworkingday]
    ,[categorytype]
  FROM 
     [dbo].[employee_shift_override]
  WHERE 
     masterentity = 'COMP123' 
     AND [employeeid] = 351 
     AND isactive = 1
     --and [date] >= @fromdate and [date] <= @todate
  ORDER BY 
     [shiftoverrideid]
     OFFSET (@page - 1) * @recordslimit ROWS
     FETCH NEXT @recordslimit ROWS ONLY
```

I would like to know what parameters can I set to `@page` and `@recordslimit` in order to ignore the `FETCH` and get all rows.

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `@page` to `1` to start from the first record.

Set `@recordslimit` to a value that is more than the number of records that you could possibly have, like `1000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that if you set `@page` to 1, you'll wind up with an offset of 0 rows, regardless of the value of `@recordslimit`.

So `@recordslimit` can be as large as you like.  Since you're just querying one table, you can pre-fetch its total record count and use that for `@recordslimit`, since you couldn't need to return more records than that.